# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs and just routing.. I have followed the tutorial on this article.. 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

i have also read the ng-book and they both seem to taught me the same procedure for implementing angular route module..

but i seem to be getting the error below.. ive also included the stack

i have tried rewriting my code in different ways like not putting myApp module in a variable but instead redeclaring it with the same angular.module(); syntax.. ive also remove each function/object to see where the error is being thrown at and it seems to be in the ngRoute module

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at <error>
at $get (https://simplysocial.firebaseapp.com/vendor.js:9101:18)
at invokeLinkFn (https://simplysocial.firebaseapp.com/vendor.js:8644:9)
at nodeLinkFn (https://simplysocial.firebaseapp.com/vendor.js:8142:11)
at compositeLinkFn (https://simplysocial.firebaseapp.com/vendor.js:7534:13)
at compositeLinkFn (https://simplysocial.firebaseapp.com/vendor.js:7538:13)
at publicLinkFn (https://simplysocial.firebaseapp.com/vendor.js:7409:30)
at link (https://simplysocial.firebaseapp.com/vendor.js:29279:7)
at invokeLinkFn (https://simplysocial.firebaseapp.com/vendor.js:8642:9)
at nodeLinkFn (https://simplysocial.firebaseapp.com/vendor.js:8142:11)(anonymous function) @ vendor.js:12314$get @ vendor.js:9101invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8644nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409$get.boundTranscludeFn @ vendor.js:7553controllersBoundTransclude @ vendor.js:8169update @ vendor.js:29229link @ vendor.js:29194invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7538publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409link @ vendor.js:29279invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409$get.boundTranscludeFn @ vendor.js:7553controllersBoundTransclude @ vendor.js:8169update @ vendor.js:29229link @ vendor.js:29194invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7538publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409link @ vendor.js:29279invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409$get.boundTranscludeFn @ vendor.js:7553controllersBoundTransclude @ vendor.js:8169update @ vendor.js:29229link @ vendor.js:29194invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7538publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409link @ vendor.js:29279invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409$get.boundTranscludeFn @ vendor.js:7553controllersBoundTransclude @ vendor.js:8169update @ vendor.js:29229link @ vendor.js:29194invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7538publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409link @ vendor.js:29279invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409$get.boundTranscludeFn @ vendor.js:7553controllersBoundTransclude @ vendor.js:8169update @ vendor.js:29229link @ vendor.js:29194invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7538publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409link @ vendor.js:29279invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409$get.boundTranscludeFn @ vendor.js:7553controllersBoundTransclude @ vendor.js:8169update @ vendor.js:29229link @ vendor.js:29194invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7538publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409link @ vendor.js:29279invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409$get.boundTranscludeFn @ vendor.js:7553controllersBoundTransclude @ vendor.js:8169update @ vendor.js:29229link @ vendor.js:29194invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7538publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409link @ vendor.js:29279invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409$get.boundTranscludeFn @ vendor.js:7553controllersBoundTransclude @ vendor.js:8169update @ vendor.js:29229link @ vendor.js:29194invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7538publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409link @ vendor.js:29279invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409$get.boundTranscludeFn @ vendor.js:7553controllersBoundTransclude @ vendor.js:8169update @ vendor.js:29229link @ vendor.js:29194invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7538publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409link @ vendor.js:29279invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409$get.boundTranscludeFn @ vendor.js:7553controllersBoundTransclude @ vendor.js:8169update @ vendor.js:29229link @ vendor.js:29194invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7538publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409link @ vendor.js:29279invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409$get.boundTranscludeFn @ vendor.js:7553controllersBoundTransclude @ vendor.js:8169update @ vendor.js:29229link @ vendor.js:29194invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7538publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409link @ vendor.js:29279invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409$get.boundTranscludeFn @ vendor.js:7553controllersBoundTransclude @ vendor.js:8169update @ vendor.js:29229link @ vendor.js:29194invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7538publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409link @ vendor.js:29279invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409$get.boundTranscludeFn @ vendor.js:7553controllersBoundTransclude @ vendor.js:8169update @ vendor.js:29229link @ vendor.js:29194invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7538publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409link @ vendor.js:29279invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409$get.boundTranscludeFn @ vendor.js:7553controllersBoundTransclude @ vendor.js:8169update @ vendor.js:29229link @ vendor.js:29194invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7534compositeLinkFn @ vendor.js:7538publicLinkFn @ vendor.js:7409link @ vendor.js:29279invokeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8642nodeLinkFn @ vendor.js:8142
```

here is also my code

```
var simplySocialApp = angular.module('simplySocialApp', ['ngRoute']);

simplySocialApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
      });

  }]);
```

thank you

Comment: which version of angular.js & angular-route.js you are using?

Comment: Couls you show `views/home.html` and its controller?

Comment: @pankajparkar her is my bower dep 
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.0",
    "normalize.css": "~3.0.3",
    "angular-route": "~1.4.1"
  }

Comment: @infaustus here is my views/home.html http://jsfiddle.net/rlynjb/1esp6ak9/

Comment: @ReinaLynBen your `angular.js` and `angular.min.js` should be in sync otherwise you will be in problem.. Eiether both should be 1.4.0 / 1.4.1

Comment: uhmmm @pankajparkar yup ive tried installing 
"dependencies": {
"angular": "~1.4.1",
"normalize.css": "~3.0.3",
"angular-route": "~1.4.1"
}
and its still giving me the same erorr.. ive also loaded angular.js first and then angular-route second but its still givng me the same error

Comment: @ReinaLynBen angular 1.3.16/1.4.0 is stable version you can use one of them.. or could you reproduce the same issue in plunkr?

Comment: here it is @pankajparkar http://plnkr.co/edit/SbRr2YTkDWk2T5iVTLiq
uhmmm it works fine on plunkr.. im thinking now if this has something to do with my built.. i am using gulp.js to combine angularjs and angular-route and minify them

Comment: try the app without minification..I think it should work..Might be you missed to use inline array annotation of dependency https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: @pankajparkar ive tried that as well.. ive found the issue.. my built is not including my templates inside views directory.. its just dumping index.html file.. when ive included other templates unto my built.. it works as it should.. :-D

on the sidenote: emberjs templates works way different then angularjs.. i mustve got use to emberjs built.. :-)

Comment: @ReinaLynBen Cool..you fixed you issue by own..thats great thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pankajparkar ive tried that as well.. ive found the issue.. my built is not including my templates inside views directory.. its just dumping index.html file.. when ive included other templates unto my built.. it works as it should.. :-D on the sidenote: emberjs templates works way different then angularjs.. i mustve got use to emberjs built.. :-)